# Consulta onde resultado igual a algum dos valores da lista

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho uma tabela de Duplicatas que possui o mês referente como string,(ex: 01/2012, 05/2016 e etc)

E preciso realizar uma consulta entre um intervalo de datas, se o campo fosse *DateTime* sei que bastaria usar *>=* e *<=* mas sendo ele uma string com mês e ano, como posso passar um parâmetro com uma lista contendo as datas que desejo

```
select * from(select ID,Duplicata,IF(Modelo ='C','Corretor',if(Modelo = 'S','Supervisor','')) as 'Tipo',(select corr_nome from corretores where corr_id = comissionado) as 'Comissionado', Valor from comissao)A1
 where (select dup_mes from duplicatas dup_mes= /*<LISTA DE VALORES QUE QUERO PESQUISAR>*/
```

P.S. A Lista ira conter os valores do intervalo de datas(01/2017, 02/2017, 03/2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar utilizar a claúsula `IN` no seu `SELECT`. 
Ex:

```
select dup_mes from duplicatas dup_mes IN ('01/2017', '02/2017', '03/2017')
```

Comment: Filipe, acho que faltou um "where" ai, não?

Comment: Eu só peguei a parte do subselect para exemplificar a utilização do `IN`, não peguei todo o `SELECT`. Mas seria algo assim: `select * from(select ID,Duplicata,IF(Modelo ='C','Corretor',if(Modelo = 'S','Supervisor','')) as 'Tipo',(select corr_nome from corretores where corr_id = comissionado) as 'Comissionado', Valor from comissao)A1
 where (select dup_mes from duplicatas dup_mes IN ('01/2017', '02/2017', '03/2017'))`

Comment: @FilipeMartins tinha colocado o final como um exemplo pois não sabia se outro comando iria substituir o select, mas no caso funcionou somente colocando o where antes de Dup_mes, seria interessante atualizar a resposta para quem pesquisar por isto ter a resposta 100% ok! obrigado por me salvar haha